# Virtualbox dhcp server not able to find vm to assign ip address

Tags: virtualbox, dhcp-server

I have been trying to run two virtual machines using Oracle Virtualbox.

virtualbox is able to assign ip address to one vm, but showing error for the second vm.

Tried to get the ip address of the two vms using VBoxManage command and their MAC addresses. Following is the result for two individual vms respectively.

[image]

From the above image, it can be observed that ip address is assigned for one vm (Green box). and error for other (Red Box).

Following is the error mesage.

> Error: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component
> DHCPServerWrap, interface IDHCPServer, callee IUnknown.

I have tried for Bridged Adapter, Host-Only adapter and NAT Network.

For all above cases, I could see that virtualbox dhcp server is not able to find vm.

Please let know what changes need to be made, so that dhcp server will be able to find vm?

Is there any chance that because of faulty vm, the virtualbox dhcp server is not able to find the vm.?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried for Bridged Adapter, Host-Only adapter and NAT Network.
>
> For all above cases, I could see that virtualbox dhcp server is not
> able to find vm.

Using Bridged networking, the VM network adapter talks to the Host Router. That has nothing to do with the VBOX DHCP setup. It is some issue with the guest network adapter.

Try making a new Ethernet adapter profile in the virtual machine.

If the networking problems in the virtual machine are enough of a problem, consider make a new VM and setting up the Network connection right away on setup.